# Pin Report to dashboard using Power BI Embed

Tags: powerbi, report, dashboard, powerbi-embedded, pinning

Do we have any APIs or any other option for pinning the visualization to the dashboard in Power BI Embedded? So that users will be able to create their dashboard. Like the option available in the Power BI service.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no API or any other option in PowerBI Embedded to pin the visual to the dashboard. To pin the visuals to the dashboard we should add in PowerBI Service manually only